# ORA-00917: missing comma. INSERT INTO statements

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00917

I'm getting a missing comma error on all 3 statements when I try to use INSERT INTO, checked over it multiple times, thanks.

```
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES 
(1.NEXTVAL, 'Simon Gould', '17 Pearson Grove', '13/10/92', 'sjpdsg@happyholidays.net', 07817333245, '24000', '13/10/15', 'engineer', 'Portuguese', '10 hours', '£500', 1.nextval);
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES 
(2.NEXTVAL, 'Josh Dawkins', '28 Mulholland Drive', '12/09/82', 'jd1982@happyholidays.net', 07801123456, '15000', '02/05/11', 'engineer', 'English', '6 hours', '£300', 2.nextval);
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES
(3.NEXTVAL, 'Michelle Arazanguiz', '75 Newport Way', '21/03/90', 'ma_holidays@happyholidays.net', 07323456456, '16000', '05/11/08', 'tour guide', 'Spanish', '0 hours', '£0', 3.nextval);
```

Comment: What is phone_number type? is salary type string?

Comment: What is `1.nextval`? Is it a sequence?

Comment: I bet you have other problems as well, but since you seem to want to hardcode the `staff_id` and `caravan_park_id` values, you don't need the `.nextval` part.  I'm curious what made you want to construct the value that way in the first place.

Comment: Hi Tony, phone_number type is just a number type
Hi David, 1.nextval - I was trying to get the primary key to auto generate, I've been playing around with the code for a while trying to get it to work so I tried a number or things
Hi Stan, Okay thank you, I was really just experimenting to try and auto generate the primary and foreign key attributes.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm), your query should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES 
(staff_id.NEXTVAL, 'Simon Gould', '17 Pearson Grove', '13/10/92', 'sjpdsg@happyholidays.net', 07817333245, '24000', '13/10/15', 'engineer', 'Portuguese', '10 hours', '£500', caravan_park_id.nextval);
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES 
(staff_id.NEXTVAL, 'Josh Dawkins', '28 Mulholland Drive', '12/09/82', 'jd1982@happyholidays.net', 07801123456, '15000', '02/05/11', 'engineer', 'English', '6 hours', '£300', caravan_park_id.nextval);
INSERT INTO staff 
(staff_id, staff_name, address, d_o_b, email, phone_number, salary, hire_date, job_role, nationality, over_time, bonus, caravan_park_id)
VALUES
(staff_id.NEXTVAL, 'Michelle Arazanguiz', '75 Newport Way', '21/03/90', 'ma_holidays@happyholidays.net', 07323456456, '16000', '05/11/08', 'tour guide', 'Spanish', '0 hours', '£0', caravan_park_id.nextval);
```

That is, use `staff_id.NEXTVAL` and `caravan_park_id.nextval` to indicate you want the next value in both these sequences.

Comment: To be clear, this answer presupposes the existence of sequences called `staff_id` and `caravan_id`.